# Prove that the following language is not regular by using the Myhill-Nerode Relation

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, regular-language

$A_3=\{a^{2^n}|n \geq 0\}$ and the alphabet is the set with the element $a$, so it's just the language whose members length are a power of 2.

Proof: Let $x=\{a^i |i \geq0\}$ and $z=a^j$ where j is odd. If $i$ is odd then there exists a way $i+j$ can be a power 2. We will pick these pairs of i,j, so $a^ia^j \in A_3$, but  if $i$ is even, this $j$ will never make the string be in the language because string length is always odd, so in this case $a^ia^j \notin A_3$. Therefore, z is an distinguishable string which implies $A_3$ is not regular.

I am not sure if this is complete because I think I am being a little bit inaccurate by generating the desired powers of two. Can this proof be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to prove non-regularity, you must find an infinite set of mutually distinguishable strings (i.e., any 2 strings in the set are distinguishable).  You haven't done that; at best, your argument only shows that $a^i$ for $i$ odd is distinguishable from $a^i$ for $i$ even.  That only gets you 2 distinguishable strings, but you need infinitely many.

Comment: Hello @Ted, I edited my thread. I added the bounds for z. I am trying to find a single distinguishable string for the set X. By doing so, I will try to show that there exists an infinite amount of pairs in $x$ that are not related by $R_{A_3}$ which implies $A_3$ is not regular because the number of equivalent classes are infinite.

Comment: So you are saying it has to be try for any $p \in x$?

Comment: I think I can fix it

Comment: I think I saw my mistake. Keep on touch with me please.

Comment: I am finding this problem to be very challenging. How would you go about creating the desired set?